# Writing to a UITextField in my storyboard but not seeing anything write to it

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I am pretty new to IOS development and I am using Xamarin IOS to accomplish this.

The issue I am having is that I have a UITextField declared automatically as an outlet called 'dateInput'. What I am trying to do is write to the text property of this textfield using a string. I am trying to do this inside another method inside my ViewController class. I have instantiated a new instance of the dateInput textfield as a UITextFIeld but when I try to write to this, nothing appears in the textfield.

If I don't create an instance of the dateInput then I just get a Null exception returned. As I said, i'm pretty new so this may just be a simple fix but cannot work it out.Any help would be appreciated.

ViewController Code:

```
public void HandleDateChange(string dateOutput){

        dateInput = new UITextField();
        dateInput.Text = dateOutput;

    }
```

And this is the code which is automatically generated for the textfield object:

```
[Outlet]
[GeneratedCode ("iOS Designer", "1.0")]
UIKit.UITextField dateInput { get; set; }
```

ViewDidLoad Method:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();


        testButton.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            PerformSegue("dateSegue", this);
        };

        testLabel.Text = "ViewDidLoad";

    }
```

The point at which the HandleDateChange method is called inside another viewcontroller:

```
partial void dateValueChanged(UIDatePicker sender)
    {
        var date = PMSimpilfied.Application.NSDateToDateTime(datePicker.Date);
        var dateConversion = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
        NewPmSheetViewController newPmSheetView = new NewPmSheetViewController();
        newPmSheetView.HandleDateChange(dateConversion);
    }
```

This is the crash I receive:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmDkv.png Log]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Jamie

Comment: try self.dateInput.text = dateOutput; right now it is assigning to different object than one created on storyboard. I am native developer not worked with Xamarin  IOS but if you have created object on the storyboard you need not instantiate it again. Can you add crash logs?

Comment: I have added the self. part but it doesn't allow me to do that as it says 'self does not appear in the current context'. I have added the crash log as an image to my original post

Comment: your method belongs to same viewController, where you have outlet of textfield, and it gets call after viewDidLoad. Right? as you specify it says 'self does not appear in the current context' I have doubt that  there is some scope problem.

Comment: Yes thats correct, I will add the ViewdidLoad method above to see if that has anything to do with it. I can change the value of dateInput.text within ViewDidLoad without any problems.

Comment: @JamieLeech When do you call the private method? Can you share this whole ViewController's code?

Comment: @LandLu Yes, the method is called inside another viewcontroller which is a popover of the currently active viewcontroller. I think this may be the issue but I need it to be returned from a popover in any case. Ive added the viewcontroller which calls this method every time the datepicker is changed.

Comment: @JamieLeech Have you solved the issues?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT Yes thank you very much for your help! Your solution works as intended!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a parameter to the `NewPmSheetViewController`, you should not configure the UIViewController's control directly. Because before the UIViewController has been loaded, all of its controls haven't been loaded.

`NewPmSheetViewController newPmSheetView = new NewPmSheetViewController();` just means you construct an instance of `NewPmSheetViewController`. It has not been loaded in the window, so all of its references would be null.

You should create a property in the `NewPmSheetViewController`, then use this property to show the `dateInput`'s Text:

```
public string dateOutput { set; get; }
```

Moreover another error is in your `dateValueChanged()` when you want to pass the date string. It seems you use UIStoryboard to initialize your UIViewController, the construct method should be like this:

```
partial void dateValueChanged(UIDatePicker sender)
{
    var date = PMSimpilfied.Application.NSDateToDateTime(datePicker.Date);
    var dateConversion = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    // This identifier string can be configured in your Storyboard called "Storyboard ID"
    NewPmSheetViewController newPmSheetView = Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("NewPmSheetViewController") as NewPmSheetViewController;
    // Pass the parameter through this property
    newPmSheetView.dateOutput = dateConversion;
    // Try to show the controller on the Window
    NavigationController.PushViewController(newPmSheetView, true);
}
```

At last in the `newPmSheetView`'s `ViewDidLoad()` event show the string on the UITextField:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    if (dateOutput != null)
    {
        dateInput.Text = dateOutput;
    }           
}
```